# Question on current sensor sampling

Tags: transistors, spi, current-measurement, igbt

I'm using this current sensor [TLI4970-D050T4](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TLI4970-D050T4-DS-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4625607bd1301562c43e04f38ad) located at the emitter leg of a power IGBT. This transistor is being switched at 10 kHz. How do I choose the convenient sampling frequency for the sensor? Is it trivial? For example, I'm sampling every 10 ms, so it's obvious I'm going to get a lot of instantaneous measurements which some of them will be zero when the transistor is off.

Comment: How are you planning on configuring the sensor's filters (datasheet, page 12)?

Comment: I'm using default settings. So, it's 18 kHz bandwidth.

Comment: Then you're wasting your time. Sampling an unfiltered 10kHz signal at 10ms intervals is unlikely to give you much useful information.

Comment: What do you recommend then? I can't change the bandwidth for now.

Comment: Sample faster - much, much faster. Other than that it depends on what you want to know about this 10kHz signal ...

Comment: How fast would you say? I'm controlling a DC motor with the IGBT at 10 kHz. So, I think the sensor gives me the average current if I sample really fast?

Comment: Do you need to detect SHORT CIRCUITS? If so, how quickly must you perform this detection?

Comment: I'm using the Overcurrent detection feature through an interrupt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I choose the convenient sampling frequency for the sensor?

This sensor has internal ADC with digital low-pass filter which has an adjustable cutoff frequency between 70 Hz and 18kHz.

If you put the sensor in the emitter of the IGBT it will only measure motor current when the IGBT is switched ON. This can work if the sensor is synchronized to the motor PWM so it samples at the correct moment. It also requires a sensor with enough bandwidth and fast enough settling time to be fully settled and the sample acquired before the IGBT turns OFF, as once it has turned off there is no current to measure.

The specific sensor you mention does not have these features, it also does not allow synchronization, so it should be set to a rather low filter cutoff frequency to get rid of the 10kHz PWM... but then **the average current measured by the sensor will be the product of motor current and duty cycle**. This seems a bit difficult to use. If you want to measure motor current, you have to put the sensor in series with the motor, not in the IGBT emitter. It has less than 1 mOhm internal resistance and it is isolated up to 2.5 kV, so putting it in series with the motor makes a lot more sense... I'm curious as to why you didn't consider this first.

If you put it in series with the motor, then you can probably use a higher cutoff frequency since the motor inductance will smooth PWM current. If you use this as part of a control loop, it's a good thing.

Using the sensor's internal overcurrent detection is excellent. However, I would NOT use an interrupt for this. Instead I would pick a micro with an dedicated pin that stops the PWM peripheral first, using only hardware, and then raises an interrupt so the micro can look at what just happened. Most microcontrollers with "motor control" feature allow this.

This has much less latency than an interrupt, it cannot be masked by a higher priority interrupt, cannot mess up due to software bugs... which is something you really want on a short-circuit protection... and it also works if the micro is in debug mode! If you use a debug probe, and single-step through the instructions, the CPU will be stopped and it will no longer react to interrupts. This means an interrupt-based OCP will not work during debug, which is when you kinda need it because you'll be messing with the circuit and probing around...

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know ( from my limited information ) I motor drives the current sampling happens at each switching cycle . ( they call it cycle-by-cycle current limit) , you need to read the current at each PWM cycle.

Usually it is done by making the PWM module trigger a ADC sampling at the beginning of the switching cycle of the IGBT/Mosfet , then the sampling time is ended automatically by the end of the On time for example ( this depends weather you are measuring peak or average current) ,this sample then is converted and compared to the allowed current and then do whatever you want ( for example decrease PWM output or cause a fault signal ... etc )

Answer (score 0):

You must specify , what you need to measure and learn.

I would use 5Mb/s serial port with 80kHz sampling rate with 18kHz BW and measure the current waveform during load change or rms current control change while decimating the rms current into a register , then after the load is characterized for step changes and controlled ramps you can reduce the BW and sampling rate while OCD alerts you for faults.  The results can be monitored using some processing for crest factor pk/avg phase shift with voltage and deviation from expected load which you have computed ahead of time then can use as part of a servo controlled output of any kind.  e.g. VFD, SMPS, motor kV/RPM etc.

Answer (score 0):

From sampling theory, it is recommended that the sampling rate be **at least** 2 times the signal frequency.  4 times the signal frequency gives you more accurate results.  So, the minimum sampling frequency you need is 20 KHZ, and 40 KHZ if you want better accuracy.